# automatic filling and submitting form with Perl :LWP

Tags: html, forms, perl, http-post, lwp-useragent

i just got into web programming with perl and I am trying to write a perl script that will go to a web page (http://211.157.104.77:8080/sipo_EN/search/tabSearch.do?method=init),
fill in the Input text field, and then submit the form. As it is not working, i wonder what url should i give "post" if not the one i already tried.

```
   $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(keep_alive => 0);     
   $ua->proxy('http', $proxy);
   $cookie_jar = new HTTP::Cookies();
   $ua->cookie_jar($cookie_jar); 
   $ua->agent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)');
   $url  ='http://211.157.104.77:8080/sipo_EN/search/tabSearch.do?method=search'; 
   $response = $ua->post( $url, { a => "03085931", b => "",
                                  c => "",d => "",e => "",
                                  f => "",g => "",h => "",
                                  i => "",j => "",k => "",
                                  l => "",m => "",

    } );

  $cgi = CGI->new();
  print $cgi->header(), $response->content();
```

After filling in the form, the Webpage returns a result list of documents, which i'd like to access in the end. I already tried to find out, and also read about  WWW::Mechanize, but since the page i'd like to access owns javascript, i think it wouldn't work. (Also there isn't really a submit button, just click events)

Best regards

Comment: If you own the resource then you may just define and call appropriate API to get what you need. And this would be MUCH easier, than emulate full scale browser with JS engine and human able to pass captchas. If you don't own the resource, and the resource doesn't expose any appropriate API to you, then it seems like kinda blackhat hacking attempt, doesn't it?

Comment: @a1111exe i don't own the resource, all i want is to start a process on the webpage and to get the search-results .. should been possible?